# Command Interface design for RTS

Tags: rts, oop

Commands may have different target type; like NONE, COORD, UNIT.
Some example commands may be: Attack (target UNIT), Move (target COORD), AttackMove (target COORD), Stop (target NONE), UseAbility (target ability.getTargetType).
Commands will be executed by UI or AI.
So in an OOP approach here, what methods should my Command interface have?
For the command execution has access to the target the command wants.

Answer (score 1):

There are not so many combinations when you write them all down.

We just have a bunch of overloaded methods alike:

```
CmdArmy(cmdType)
CmdArmy(cmdType, Unit)
CmdArmy(cmdType, Coord)
CmdArmy(cmdType, Param)
CmdArmy(cmdType, Coord, Param)
```

Where `cmdType` is a key alike:

```
ctAttack, ctMove, ctStop, ctAbility, ctEtc ...
```

It's not OOP, but it's going along the lines of KISS quite well.

Comment: +1, but I want my commands to be objects so I can store them in queues, histories and send them over the network. I'm thinking of a CommandData class, a CommandType interface, and a final Command class composite both type and data. CommandProcessSystem will just execute the CommandType.execute with the CommandData.

Comment: Sounds like an unnecessary complication, if you can store any command in 12 bytes by a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a simple base class. That allows you to write commands like this (You didn't specify a language so I'll write something C#-like, using some concepts from Unity):

```
abstract class Command
{
    abstract string Description {get;} //Maybe you want all commands to have a description in your UI
    abstract string Name {get;}//This is also for the UI. Neither of these affect your logic
    //...More things you want all commands to have

    abstract void Apply(UnitController unitController, Action onCompletedCallback);

}

class MoveCommand : Command
{
    override string Description 
    {
       return "This moves a Unit" //You'd probably have some logic here for localized strings instead of a literal
    }

    override string Name 
    {
        return "Move" //See above
    }

    private readonly Vector3 TargetLocation;

    //...More command specific members

    MoveCommand(Vector3 targetLocation)
    {
        TargetLocation = targetLocation;
    }

    override void Apply(UnitController unitController,Action onCompletedCallback)
    {

        //Something along the lines of:
        unitController.MoveTo(TargetLocation) //Unit controller owns the logic for movement 

        // --------------------Or---------------
        var pathFinder = unitController.GetComponent<Pathfinder>(); 
        if(pathFinder == null) 
             //Throw some exception
        pathFinder.Move(TargetLocation,onCompletedCallback); //Path finder owns the logic for movement

        //---------------------Or---------------
        var movementMangager = GlobalManagers.Resolve<IUnitMovementManager>();
        movementManager.MoveUnit(unitController,TargetLocation); //Some class owns the logic for movement.
    }
}
```

Comment: so I need to repeat the target logic in all my command and hard-code downcast every command in order to use it?

Comment: My last comment got mangled, what I was trying to say was "You wouldn't need to repeat any logic, but without knowing more about your setup I can't go into details on how to prevent repeated logic, but I can give a small example.", I added the examples

Comment: still have to downcast Command to MoveCommand in order to set TargetLocation; so, hard code?

Comment: `TargetLocation` is part of the constructor and only used within the `MoveCommand` class. So you call the constructor for `MoveCommand` with `TargetLocation` (eg. `new MoveCommand(SomeLocation)`), but pass it around as a `Command`. You don't ever need to cast `Command` to `MoveCommand`, or vice-versa, because `MoveCommand` inherits from `Command` which exposes `Apply`, and `TargetLocation` can only be set from the constructor of `MoveCommand` (and should only be accessible from `MoveCommand`, I simply omitted scope in my example).

Comment: To clarify my intention of the use of TargetLocation I made it a `private readonly` member.

Comment: then we must explicitly call whatever constructor of your MoveCommand or any of your command, so no OCP I guess

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if you're referring to the open/closed principle, I don't see how constructors change compliance (or how it applies to programming game logic to be completely honest, it's a concept I see more often in production environments where code has to pass a multitude of unit tests.). Nothing is stopping you from extending `MoveCommand`. You'd simply create a derived type such as `SpecializedMoveCommand`.